# Paypal REST SDK Execute payment returns False

Tags: rest, paypal

we are using the paypal rest SDK in a python web app. For most customers it works just fine where I can execute a payment after the user has logged in and been redirected back to my site. There are a couple of customer's however for whom the following call returns a False instead of an object:

paymentResult = payment.execute({"payer_id": payer_id})

The payment object in this case looks just the same as in the cases where it works. It seems to consistently fail for some customers and consistently work for others. What are the reasons that the execute statement would return a False? Thanks.